# PushSharp stops at StopAllServices

Tags: c#, windows, apple-push-notifications

I use PushSharp-2.2.1.0 and I can't go up in version because of the program using it is built in .NET 4.0. For now I only use PushSharp.Apple.

On my local machine (Windows 10) I can run my stuff with no problems. Here I run the program as a Console Application.

When I run the stuff on another server (Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2003) I get problems. The only thing I can see from my log is that it stopps at StopAllServices. Here I run the program as an installed Windows Service.

On both machines I use the same files (incl. .p12 file(s)).

I have checked the NewtonSoft dll and it's the same as the one PushSharp uses and the same I use on the local machine. The use that the service run as has all permissions to the .p12 files.

Does anyone know what I can do to get it up and running?

Answer (score 0):

By re-building the PushSharp.Apple project with updated (from 6 something to 8 something) version of Newtonsoft.dll to match other projects in the solution and with removing the CheckProductionCertificateMatching in ApplePushChannelSettings (also in PushSharp.Apple) I got this working for now with PushSharp.2.2.1.0.